# Sonarqube hangs when storing results in database with java.sql.SQLException

Tags: mysql, gradle, sonarqube

I was trying to install sonar instance on EC2 Ubuntu server and migrate the old mysql database to the server. It had worked fine until I updated Sonargraph, Java and Git plugins and wanted to rebuild sonar using Gradle. The build hangs for 30-50min when trying to store results in mysql database and then fails with java.sql.SQLException: Already closed.

Here's the part of the error log that I receive when running gradlew:

```
15:22:49.747 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :sonarqube FAILED
15:22:49.748 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :sonarqube (Thread[Daemon Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 45 mins 23.097 secs.
15:22:49.748 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon Thread 3,5,main]] finished, busy: 45 mins 58.672 secs, idle: 0.058 secs
15:22:49.752 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:22:49.752 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
15:22:49.753 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:22:49.753 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
15:22:49.753 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
15:22:49.753 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Unable to execute Sonar
15:22:49.754 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:22:49.754 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
15:22:49.755 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
15:22:49.755 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
15:22:49.755 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
15:22:49.756 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
15:22:49.756 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
15:22:49.756 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
15:22:49.756 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
15:22:49.756 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
15:22:49.757 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
15:22:49.757 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
15:22:49.757 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
15:22:49.757 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
15:22:49.757 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
15:22:49.758 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
15:22:49.758 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
15:22:49.758 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
15:22:49.758 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
15:22:49.758 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
15:22:49.759 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
15:22:49.759 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
15:22:49.759 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
15:22:49.759 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
15:22:49.759 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
15:22:49.760 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
15:22:49.760 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
15:22:49.760 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
15:22:49.760 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
15:22:49.761 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
15:22:49.761 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
15:22:49.761 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
15:22:49.761 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
15:22:49.761 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
15:22:49.762 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
15:22:49.762 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
15:22:49.762 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
15:22:49.762 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
15:22:49.762 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
15:22:49.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
15:22:49.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
15:22:49.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
15:22:49.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
15:22:49.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
15:22:49.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
15:22:49.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
15:22:49.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
15:22:49.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
15:22:49.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
15:22:49.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
15:22:49.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
15:22:49.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:60)
15:22:49.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
15:22:49.766 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
15:22:49.766 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
15:22:49.766 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
15:22:49.766 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
15:22:49.766 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
15:22:49.766 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
15:22:49.767 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
15:22:49.767 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
15:22:49.767 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
15:22:49.767 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
15:22:49.767 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
15:22:49.768 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
15:22:49.768 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:51)
15:22:49.768 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
15:22:49.768 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
15:22:49.769 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
15:22:49.769 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
15:22:49.769 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
15:22:49.769 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
15:22:49.770 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
15:22:49.770 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
15:22:49.770 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
15:22:49.770 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
15:22:49.770 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
15:22:49.771 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask.run(SonarQubeTask.java:50)
15:22:49.771 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
15:22:49.771 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
15:22:49.771 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
15:22:49.772 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
15:22:49.772 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:533)
15:22:49.772 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:516)
15:22:49.772 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
15:22:49.772 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
15:22:49.773 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 66 more
15:22:49.773 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot release connection
15:22:49.773 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
15:22:49.774 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
15:22:49.774 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
15:22:49.774 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
15:22:49.774 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.closeConnection(ConnectionManager.java:478)
15:22:49.774 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.aggressiveRelease(ConnectionManager.java:429)
15:22:49.775 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.afterTransaction(ConnectionManager.java:316)
15:22:49.775 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.afterTransactionCompletion(JDBCContext.java:248)
15:22:49.775 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:158)
15:22:49.775 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:54)
15:22:49.776 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.commit(JpaDatabaseSession.java:83)
15:22:49.776 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.commitAndClose(JpaDatabaseSession.java:69)
15:22:49.776 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.stop(JpaDatabaseSession.java:64)
15:22:49.777 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
15:22:49.777 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.stop(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:96)
15:22:49.777 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.stop(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:88)
15:22:49.778 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.stop(AbstractBehavior.java:179)
15:22:49.778 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.stop(Stored.java:141)
15:22:49.778 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.stop(Stored.java:118)
15:22:49.779 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stopAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1047)
15:22:49.779 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stop(DefaultPicoContainer.java:802)
15:22:49.779 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.stopComponents(ComponentContainer.java:123)
15:22:49.780 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.stopComponents(ComponentContainer.java:118)
15:22:49.780 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.stop(Batch.java:107)
15:22:49.780 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
15:22:49.780 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
15:22:49.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
15:22:49.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 80 more
15:22:49.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Already closed.
15:22:49.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection.close(PoolableConnection.java:114)
15:22:49.782 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.close(PoolingDataSource.java:191)
15:22:49.782 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.closeConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:97)
15:22:49.782 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.closeConnection(ConnectionManager.java:474)
15:22:49.782 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 102 more
15:22:49.783 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:22:49.783 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
15:22:49.783 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
15:22:49.784 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
15:22:49.784 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 46 mins 1.31 secs
```

When I go over the same procedure with sonar running on my local computer (same config file settings, etc), gradle build doesn't hang and finishes successfully.

I'm using following versions:

- sonar 5.1.1 (application)
- sonarqube 1.0 (gradle plugin)
- gradle 1.11
- java 8 (project to analyse)
- mysql 5.5.43 (database sonar connects to)
- java plugin 3.3 (sonar plugin)
- sonargraph 3.4.2 (sonar plugin)
- git 1.1 (sonar plugin)

Why does the database step hang for so long and fail?

Comment: Where is the analysis running? This can have a huge impact on performances, because the Gradle SonarQube task makes lots of DB read & writes. (will be fixed in SQ 5.2 BTW)

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam we use c4.xlarge ec2 instance (4 vCPU, 7.5GiB). There's nothing else on running on that instance.

Comment: If you say that it was working fine until you upgraded some plugins, have you tried getting back to the original situation and then update the plugins one by one?

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam yes, but I added all the plugins all at once

Comment: Could you try again and do it one by one in order to find if one of the plugins is guilty?

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam do plugins work differently in Lunux vs iOS environment?

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam could it be some networking issue with ec2 instance instead?

Comment: Plugins should be working in the same way - whatever the OS. This can indeed be networking issue, but if you're telling me that it was working until you updated Sonargraph, Java and Git plugins, then this is weird.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam yes, when Sonar was updated and configured on my local computer, I was just using localhost. But then when I did the same update for remote ec2 instance, I had to use the database on ec2, so there might be some networking issue? but I checked the connection to database and it was ok though..

Comment: There must be some networking issues indeed, because it should be working correctly. For instance, our live demo SQ instance (http://nemo.sonarqube.org) is on EC2 (with a MySQL too) and we have no problem.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam hmm this answer helps and discourages at the same time..I'm not sure how I could proceed. Not really sure I want to look into low-level networking issues happening on the ec2. Any suggestions?