# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown

Tags: mysql, svn, jdbc, ant, sonarqube

Whenever I build a job in Hudson, it always fails right at the very end when trying to store the results in the database. The whole job usually takes around an hour to build and fail.

The source files are stored on an SVN server and can be downloaded and edited locally. Once I verify that the job is able to build successfully locally, I commit any changes to the SVN.

I recently switched to an ANT-based approach which aligns the ant target to match the convention reviewer. So I created a sonar.xml file that contains a target called sonar_scan, which is called in the build.xml file of the project.

I have set the net_read_timeout, net_write_timeout and the innodb_lock_wait_timeout to 10 minutes, rather than their default values of 60 seconds or less. The wait_timeout is set to 8 hours, so I know that the wait_timeout is not the problem.

- The database I'm using is mysql version 5.6.25
- The version of Sonar I'm using is 5.1

The full error message I receive is:

```
[sonar:sonar] 19:09:43.831 ERROR - JDBC commit failed    
[sonar:sonar] com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown.
    [sonar:sonar]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    [sonar:sonar]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    [sonar:sonar]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    [sonar:sonar]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    [sonar:sonar]   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    [sonar:sonar]   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    [sonar:sonar]   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    [sonar:sonar]   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    [sonar:sonar]   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    [sonar:sonar]   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    [sonar:sonar]   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:1611) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:334) ~[sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.commit(PoolingDataSource.java:211) ~[sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commitAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:170) ~[sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:146) ~[sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:54) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.commit(JpaDatabaseSession.java:83) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.commitAndClose(JpaDatabaseSession.java:69) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.stop(JpaDatabaseSession.java:64) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    [sonar:sonar]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    [sonar:sonar]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    [sonar:sonar]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.stop(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:96) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.stop(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:88) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.stop(AbstractBehavior.java:179) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.stop(Stored.java:141) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.stop(Stored.java:118) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stopAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1047) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stop(DefaultPicoContainer.java:802) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.stopComponents(ComponentContainer.java:123) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.stopComponents(ComponentContainer.java:118) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.stop(Batch.java:107) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48) [sonar-runner-batch1253226961910621726.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    [sonar:sonar]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    [sonar:sonar]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    [sonar:sonar]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87) [sonar-ant-task-2.3.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75) [sonar-ant-task-2.3.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_45]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69) [sonar-ant-task-2.3.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50) [sonar-ant-task-2.3.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102) [sonar-ant-task-2.3.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100) [sonar-ant-task-2.3.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.launchAnalysis(SonarTask.java:51) [sonar-ant-task-2.3.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:46) [sonar-ant-task-2.3.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292) [ant.jar:1.9.2]
    [sonar:sonar]   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    [sonar:sonar]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106) [ant.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348) [ant.jar:1.9.2]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435) [ant.jar:1.9.2]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456) [ant.jar:1.9.2]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393) [ant.jar:1.9.2]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364) [ant.jar:1.9.2]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41) [ant.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248) [ant.jar:1.9.2]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851) [ant.jar:1.9.2]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235) [ant.jar:1.9.2]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280) [ant-launcher.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109) [ant-launcher.jar:na]
    [sonar:sonar] 19:09:43.831 WARN  - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
    [sonar:sonar] 19:09:43.831 ERROR - Already closed.

    BUILD FAILED
    D:\SVN_7_1\buildscripts\sonar.xml:168: org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.launchAnalysis(SonarTask.java:51)
        at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:46)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot release connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.closeConnection(ConnectionManager.java:478)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.aggressiveRelease(ConnectionManager.java:429)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.afterTransaction(ConnectionManager.java:316)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.afterTransactionCompletion(JDBCContext.java:248)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:158)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:54)
        at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.commit(JpaDatabaseSession.java:83)
        at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.commitAndClose(JpaDatabaseSession.java:69)
        at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.stop(JpaDatabaseSession.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.stop(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:96)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.stop(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:88)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.stop(AbstractBehavior.java:179)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.stop(Stored.java:141)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.stop(Stored.java:118)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stopAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1047)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stop(DefaultPicoContainer.java:802)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.stopComponents(ComponentContainer.java:123)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.stopComponents(ComponentContainer.java:118)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.stop(Batch.java:107)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Already closed.
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection.close(PoolableConnection.java:114)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.close(PoolingDataSource.java:191)
        at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.closeConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.closeConnection(ConnectionManager.java:474)
        ... 54 more

    Total time: 42 minutes 5 seconds
```

I have searched everywhere for a possible solution and so far I haven't been able to find one. If anyone could suggest something I haven't done already then I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have plugins installed ? Which versions ?
Please note solely InnoDb is supported. No support for MyISAM

Comment: Whatever plugins came with the installation of mysql. I didn't change or add any other plugins. But if you need specifics I'll try to find the exact plugins. I think MyISAM is only compatible with mysql 5.5 or lower; I have mysql 5.6.25 installed. I haven't seen any mention of MyISAM anywhere in the project, so I doubt I have that installed.

Comment: @Teryk-SonarSourceTeam I don't know if you saw my reply because I didn't tag you. My mistake!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this other unanswered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061365/sonarqube-hangs-when-storing-results-in-database-with-java-sql-sqlexception

Comment: @MarkO'Connor yes it's quite similar - however the first error that leads to the following errors in are different. The other question has a _TaskExecutionException_. My error is a _MySQLNonTransientConnectionException_.

Answer (score 3):

Network instability

reappear code:

```
con.query()
sleep(10) //when sleep shutdown your network 
conn.roolback()
```